# What is the most efficient way to move through a PHP array a number of times in one direction or another?

Tags: php, arrays, modulo

Easy example:
Taking as a reference the English abecedary (range A-Z). If I'm given a letter - let's say 'a' - and a number - let's say '2' - I would need to find out what's the letter 2 positions onwards.
Answer would be 'c' ('a'--> 1 move:'b' --> 2 moves:'c')

Of course, you could be given a number larger than the size of the abecedary letters, which is 26. Since the rule is that after letter z comes letter a again, this means that if in the previous example number 26 was passed the letter we would need to find would be 'a'.

One last case scenario for the problem is that you may receive a negative number. So if letter 'a' is provided with number '-3', the answer would be 'x' ('a'--> 1 move:'z' --> 2 moves:'y' --> 3 moves:'x').

This is the code I have so far:

```
function getNewLetter($letter, $number) {

    $letters = range('A', 'Z');

    if ($number >= 0) {
        return $letters[($number + array_search($letter, $letters) % 26)%26];
    } else {
        return $letters[($number - (array_search($letter, $letters) % 26))%26];
    }
}

echo getNewLetter("H", 4);      // correctly prints out L
echo getNewLetter("H", 26);       // correctly prints out H
echo getNewLetter("H", -4);     // throws undefined offset -11 error
```

There are two main problems with my function:

- Even though I make it work with positive numbers, it takes time for the compiler to return an answer so I'm afraid it is a very time-consuming operation that could be sorted out more easily.
- My function approach does not work for negative numbers. I'm very aware of what an undefined offset is, it can't access a negative index of my array. I just cannot figure out how to make the modulo operator work backwards...

Any helping hand on how to solve this would have my heartfelt thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do it:

```
function getNewLetter(string $letter, int $number): string
{
    $newOrd = (ord($letter) + $number - 65) % 26;
    if ($newOrd < 0) {
        $newOrd += 26;
    }

    return chr(65 + $newOrd);
}
```

It simply uses a modulo 26 on the ordinal value of the new letter, relative to that of the letter A (65). If it's < 0, it adds 26 again to "fix" it back.

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/qCidW)**

Comment: I uploaded your method updated to work with both uppercase and lowercase letters, just in case it helps other people.

Comment: @assensi Sure thing (didn't realize you needed it to work with lowercase letters as well, but seems like you figured it out ).

Answer (score 0):

Taking a modulo 26 is a correct idea.

This is because, offset of `1` is the same as offset of `27`. Offset of `0` is the same as offset `26`,`52` etc and so on and so forth.

Taking modulo 26 for negative numbers also applies the same logic as rotation for `-27` is the same as rotation for `-1`.

---

So, the code is straightforward.

- Apply modulo 26 to the number.
- Take ascii value of current char and add "number" to it.
- If the new ascii value is within the range of 65 and 90, return the char value.
- If new ascii value exceeds 90, consume the offset till 90 and return chr() of it + 64. Same applies vice versa if value goes below 65.

**Snippet:**

```
function getNewLetter($letter, $number) {
    $number = $number % 26;
    $new_ascii_value = ord($letter) + $number;
    if($new_ascii_value < 65){
        $number = abs($number) - (ord($letter) - 65);
        return chr(91 - $number);
    }else if($new_ascii_value >= 91){
        return chr(64 + ($new_ascii_value - 90));
    }
    return chr($new_ascii_value);
}
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/0Yhkm

Answer (score 0):

Jeto's method improved to return the right answer with either uppercase or lowercase letters:

```
function getNewLetter(string $letter, int $number): string {

    $movement = $letter < 'a' ? 65 : 97;      // Depending on case, letter 'a' starts at different numbers of ASCII table

    $newOrd = (ord($letter) + $number - $movement) % 26;
    if ($newOrd < 0) {
        $newOrd += 26;
    }

    return chr($movement + $newOrd);
}
```

Here some passed tests to try out the method:

```
echo getNewLetter("h", 4), PHP_EOL;
echo getNewLetter("H", 4), PHP_EOL;
echo getNewLetter("h", -4), PHP_EOL;
echo getNewLetter("H", -4), PHP_EOL;
echo getNewLetter("h", 26), PHP_EOL;
echo getNewLetter("H", 26), PHP_EOL;
echo getNewLetter("H", 27), PHP_EOL;
echo getNewLetter("H", -26), PHP_EOL;
echo getNewLetter("H", -27), PHP_EOL;
echo PHP_EOL;
echo getNewLetter("a", -2), PHP_EOL;
echo getNewLetter("A", -2), PHP_EOL;
echo getNewLetter("b", -3), PHP_EOL;
echo getNewLetter("B", -3), PHP_EOL;
echo PHP_EOL;
echo getNewLetter("Z", 2), PHP_EOL;
echo getNewLetter("Z", 26), PHP_EOL;
echo getNewLetter("Z", 27), PHP_EOL;
echo getNewLetter("Z", -26), PHP_EOL;
echo getNewLetter("Z", -27), PHP_EOL;
echo PHP_EOL;
echo getNewLetter("A", -1), PHP_EOL;
echo getNewLetter("A", -27), PHP_EOL;
```